Getting data between 2 points in SQL Server
I have a table similar to the screenshot shown below, and I need a query to retrieve the rows between 2 points:



START_POINT
END_POINT




1
2


2
3


3
4


4
5


5
6


6
7


7
8


8
9


9
10


10
11


11
12



For example, in the query, if I have START_POINT: 4 and END_POINT: 10, the following data should be returned:



START_POINT
END_POINT




4
5


5
6


6
7


7
8


8
9


9
10



I have this query but it return the rows until the first row
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT START_POINT, END_POINT
    FROM table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT si.START_POINT, si.END_POINT
    FROM table1 si
    INNER JOIN cte ON cte.START_POINT = si.END_POINT
)
SELECT * FROM cte

Current result:



START_POINT
END_POINT




1
2


2
3


3
4


4
5


5
6


6
7


7
8


8
9


9
10



What should I change to get the excepted results?

Update 1
I have inserted the wrong query, correct query:
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT START_POINT, END_POINT
    FROM table1
    WHERE END_POINT = 10

    UNION ALL

    SELECT si.START_POINT, si.END_POINT
    FROM table1 si
    INNER JOIN cte ON cte.START_POINT = si.END_POINT
)
SELECT * FROM cte

Also the data is not always in sequence number, for example if I have this table:



START_POINT
END_POINT




1
2


2
5


5
3


3
4


4
9


9
7


7
10


10
8


8
6



if i select Start point: 2 and End point: 9, the following should return:



START_POINT
END_POINT




2
5


5
3


3
4


4
9




SELECT START_POINT, END_POINT  FROM table1 where start_point=4   Please try this

I don't get this, can't you simply do SELECT * FROM table WHERE START_POINT >= 4 AND END_POINT <= 10?

Add a where to your CTE?

We don't post images of sample data or results here. It's rude to the people trying to help you, because it forces them to retype the data to create a test case.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Now I realize the sample data is very poor. Make other steps than +1.

You need to clarify what "between" mean. Perhaps it would help us to understand why you thought a recursive query is involved.

I am sorry I am now with posting on stack overflow, I have updated my question because I think i explained poorly before.

The general test for overlapping ranges is Start1 < End2 AND Start2 < End1. So your query could be:
DECLARE @StartPoint INT = 4
DECLARE @EndPoint INT = 10

SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE START_POINT < @EndPoint
AND @StartPoint < END_POINT
-- AND END_POINT > @StartPoint -- Alternate test, if you prefer

This does not make any assumptions on the source table ranges, so those ranges may have gaps, duplicates, or arbitrarily overlapping ranges.
However, if you only want rows having ranges entirely contained withing the reference range, you can use:
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE START_POINT >= @StartPoint
AND END_POINT <= @EndPoint

For your data, the results are the same, but if you had a row with (START_POINT, END_POINT) = (2,5) or (9,11), the results would be different.
See this db<>fiddle.

Could you check Update 1, I think I did not explain what I needed clearly before

@10x2 - Can you explain your logic in words instead of just an example? I do not understand why the desired results have the rows that it does. Rows 5..3, 9..7, and 8..6 are descending ranges seemingly within the 2..9 range, but only the 5..3 is included in your results.

SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE value >= start_point AND value <= end_point;


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
